# Petsc error when running Openmdao v1.7.3 tutorials and benchmarks

Tags: openmdao

I have tried running the Openmdao paraboloid tutorial as well as benchmarks and I consistently receive the same error which reads as following:

```
[0]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR: Caught signal number 11 SEGV: Segmentation Violation, probably memory access out of range
[0]PETSC ERROR: Try option -start_in_debugger or -on_error_attach_debugger
[0]PETSC ERROR: or see http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html#valgrind
[0]PETSC ERROR: or try http://valgrind.org on GNU/linux and Apple Mac OS X to find memory corruption errors
[0]PETSC ERROR: configure using --with-debugging=yes, recompile, link, and run 
[0]PETSC ERROR: to get more information on the crash
---------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_abort was invoked on rank 0 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD with errorcode 59.
NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes MPI to kill all MPI processes.
you may or may not see output from other processes, depending on exactly when Open MPI kills them.
```

I don't understand why this error is occurring and what I can do to be able to run OpenMDAO without getting this error. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: could you give some details on which platform you're running on? Why python you installed, and how you installed MPI and petsc?

Comment: *what python you installed (not "why python you installed")

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I have python 2.7.12, and I installed mpi and petsc installed via pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something has not gone well with your PETSc install. Its hard to debug that from afar though. It could be in your MPI install, or your PETSc install, or your petsc4py install. I suggest not install PETSc or PETSc4Py through pip though. I've had mixed success with that. Both can be installed from source without tremendous difficulty.

However, to run the tutorials you don't need to have PETSc installed. You could remove those packages and the tutorials will run correctly in serial for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that. Also, does that mean that mpi and petsc will be automatically used if present on the system?

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Comment: they shouldn't be automatically used. But they are imported, and I suspect that they were dying on the import. 

you have to specifically turn on petsc/mpi for them to be used during runtime though